# \hyphenatedurl with % in bibtex file

Tags: bibtex, context

How to use

```
@misc{kraft,
author = "Kraft, Nathan",
title = "Mr Kraft's Virtual Filing Cabinet",
year = "2015",
howpublished = "\hyphenatedurl{http://mrkraft.wikispaces.com/Mr+Kraft%27s+Virtual+Filing+Cabinet}"
}
```

(note % in howpublished) in ConTeXt? If I put `\%27s`, then I get `\%27` in pdf. If not escaped, I get error.

Comment: Have you tried to use just `\url` instead? Bibtex should take care of the linebreaking actually. At least `biblatex` (which I hereby recommend) can do that.

Comment: Member for over two year, several questions, and no MWE: -1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug in ConTeXt.  First of all, `\hyphenatedurl` cannot handle `%` (This seems to be by design).  Second, the btx mechanism treats `%` as comment character in the BibTeX file and drops everything after it (I reported this on the [mailing list](https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2017/088676.html)).  Third, you are abusing `howpublished` and should be using the `url` field.

As a workaround, just URL-decode `%27` which is `'`.

```
\startbuffer[references]
  @misc{kraft,
    author = "Kraft, Nathan",
    title = "Mr Kraft's Virtual Filing Cabinet",
    year = "2015",
    url = "http://mrkraft.wikispaces.com/Mr+Kraft's+Virtual+Filing+Cabinet"
  }
\stopbuffer

\setupinteraction[state=start]

\usebtxdataset[references.buffer]
\usebtxdefinitions[apa]

\starttext

\nocite[kraft]
\placelistofpublications

\stoptext
```

[image]

---

If you are really keen on abusing the `howpublished` field, another workaround is to make `\hyphenatedurl` aware that by `\%` you mean `%`.  Note the missing hyperlink!

```
\startbuffer[references]
  @misc{kraft,
    author = "Kraft, Nathan",
    title = "Mr Kraft's Virtual Filing Cabinet",
    year = "2015",
    howpublished = "\hyphenatedurl{http://mrkraft.wikispaces.com/Mr+Kraft\%27s+Virtual+Filing+Cabinet}"
  }
\stopbuffer

\setupinteraction[state=start]

\usebtxdataset[references.buffer]
\usebtxdefinitions[apa]

\appendtoks
  \let\%\letterpercent
\to \everyhyphenatedurl

\starttext

\nocite[kraft]
\placelistofpublications

\stoptext
```

[image]

---

Another hackish solution is to set the category code of `%` to "other" when outputting the bibliography.  That way you do not have to escape `%` in the bib file.

```
\startbuffer[references]
  @misc{kraft,
    author = "Kraft, Nathan",
    title = "Mr Kraft's Virtual Filing Cabinet",
    year = "2015",
    url = "http://mrkraft.wikispaces.com/Mr+Kraft%27s+Virtual+Filing+Cabinet"
  }
\stopbuffer

\setupinteraction[state=start]

\usebtxdataset[references.buffer]
\usebtxdefinitions[apa]
\setuplist[btx][before={\catcode\commentasciicode\othercatcode}]

\starttext

\nocite[kraft]
\placelistofpublications

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but `url` is not displayed in `aps` style.

Comment: Can I use `\url` and `%` without scaping it?

Comment: @somenxavier Yes, the `url` field is not displayed in the APS style which is by design.  See the updated answer on how to not having to escape `%` in the bib file.  (Also works with your weird `howpublished = "\hyphenatedurl{...}"`)

Comment: thanks. Last answer is what I was looking for. Is there any AMS like style? I suspect we have only APS and APA, haven't we?

Comment: @somenxavier There is no AMS style yet.  Available styles are APS for numeric and APA for authoryear (and `default`, whatever that is).